# TypeError: SP.ClientContext is undefined

Tags: javascript, form

I tried to add data to a list using a HTML Form and Javascript.

When I sent the data to the list I got `TypeError: SP.ClientContext is undefined`. **After I cleared the cache and cookies everything worked fine** (the data was sent and appeared in the list) but when I tried to send a new request the error appeared again, and didn't go away without clearing the cache.

*How can I send my data without clearing the cache every time?*

My code:

```
<table id="formular" style="width:800px; margin:0 auto">

<tr>

     <td>Technician Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="tech_name"></td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Technician's comments/recommendations:</td>
    <td><textarea name="tech_comments"></textarea></td>
</tr>


<tr>

    <td></td><td><button onclick="myFunction(event);">Send</button></td>

</tr>

</table>




</div>

<script>

function myFunction(event){


    event.preventDefault();
//alert("INTRA!");



var tech_name = $("input[name='WPQ2tech_name']").val();
var tech_comments = $("input[name='WPQ2tech_comments']").val();



    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Requests');

    //alert(oList);

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');

    oListItem.set_item('Tech_name', tech_name);
    oListItem.set_item('Tech_comments', tech_comments);
    oListItem.set_item('Status', 'Pending');

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );


}



function onQuerySucceeded() {
    console.log('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
    alert("The Request has been sent");
    window.location.reload();
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    alert("The request has not been sent. Please try again.");
}


</script>
```

**EDIT**

I changed my code to

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){

        $("#send_form").click(function(event){
          //do all the stuff here - get the ids, update the list
         }
    }, 'sp.js'); });
```

Now it seems it never reaches the function when I hit send.
Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I got it working by using the code below but **SP.ClientContext is undefined**
still appears.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#send_form").click(function(){

        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myFunction(), "sp.js"); 
    });

});

function myFunction(){
....
}
```

Comment: Try to surround with `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() { ... }, 'sp.js');`

Comment: @eirikb Thank you for answering. Now it seems like it never reaces the function. I'll update in the question

Comment: @eirikb I updated my question, please be so kind and help me to find the solution. Thank you

Comment: Your updated code does not reflect my comment (missing `'sp.js`)

Comment: @eirikb I forgot to add this part here, but it was in the code.

Comment: @eirikb I updated the question

Comment: Try removing parantheses from `myFunction()`, because now you are passing the result of that function as the first argument to `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`, which is `undefined` - instead pass the function reference

Comment: @eirikb I got it working! By using SP.SOD.executeFunc(key, functionName, fn); actually SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", myFunction); The function you told me about - ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded doesn't work on published pages

Comment: ok great. Please note that you pass `myFunction` as reference in your `executeFunc` example, which is not the same as you did with `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to use the Script On Demand is this

```
if(!SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myFunction, 'sp.js')){ 
  LoadSodByKey('sp.js');
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
$(document).ready(function (){
 SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function()
 {
    //function calls or code to be executed
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by using `SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", myFunction);`

The other function, `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` doesn't work on published pages.

So here's the button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="addValue();" value="send">
```

And here's the function:

```
function addValue(){

    SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", 'SP.ClientContext', myFunction);

}


function myFunction(){
//do all the stuff
}
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer if it's a valid solution. Please see this [help page](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please add this to your asp page:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="sp.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="sp.runtime.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="sp.core.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
```