# SP.ClientContext is undefined

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, csom

Using JavaScript Client Context Code:

```
 var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

after above Code execute error I get the following error

> SP.ClientContext is undefined

in Client Context Code

Comment: Where have you put the code?

Comment: Maybe paste ``SP.ClientContext is undefined```in that search box at the top right of the page?

Answer (score 7):

You got the error because the `'SP.ClientContext'` in `'sp.js'` is not loaded

Now, Add your context code in a function

```
function myFunction() {
 var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 ...
}
```

Then, call the function as below which ensures the file `'sp.js'` containing `'SP.ClientContext'` function is loaded first and then runs `'myFunction'`

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', myFunction);
```

Comment: how to pass value in the Function?

Comment: I hate SharePoint more everyday. Up to yesterday my code worked without loading `SP.js`, today not anymore...

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure `sp.js` file is loaded before you can access CSOM.

Use a code structured like this, in the same `.js` file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      //Do not execute jsom until sp.js file has loaded.
      ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myFunctionToBeExecuted, "sp.js");
});
```

The `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function1, jsFile.js)` makes sure that your `function1` is only called after `jsFile.js` is loaded. It's safer to place this within a jQuery `$(document).ready(function(){});` to make sure your function gets called when everything else is ready.

Now you go ahead and just define your function. So at the end your code should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     //Do not execute jsom until sp.js file has loaded.
     ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myFunctionToBeCalled, "sp.js");
});

function myFunctionToBeCalled(){
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    // Rest of your code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Client Side Object Model works a bit different as on the server side. Before you can use an object you must first load it and then you must execute a query to retrieve the object

Use `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` 
Reference link

[CSOM client context undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575047/why-sp-clientcontext-get-current-throws-uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a)

[Client context undefined](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136592/typeerror-sp-clientcontext-is-undefined)